# Textbox filtering in Report design

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

How do I filter a textbox expression when doing reports? I did something like this

```
= Sum(Fields!student_points.Value < 60, "StudentDisengangementDataSet")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get it right. You mean you want to display the amount of student_points fields that have value < 60?

If so, then try something like this:

```
= Sum(IIF((Fields!student_points.Value) < 60, 1, Nothing), "StudentDisengangementDataSet")
```

which means, if student_points.Value < 60, count it (+1), else do not and return the amount of the occurances.

or if you just want to sum the values of numbers that are < 60, then:

```
= Sum(IIF((Fields!student_points.Value) < 60, Fields!student_points.Value, Nothing), "StudentDisengangementDataSet")
```

Either way I didn't test it.